# php get unknown object key

Tags: php, json, object

I have a JSON database that looks something like this:

```
"media": {
        "1": {
            "title": "Test Image",
            "description": "This is a test image",
            "thumb": "test.thumb.jpg",
            "full": "img-2007720.jpg"
        },
        "2": {
            "title": "Test2 Image",
            "description": "This is a test image",
            "thumb": "test.thumb.jpg",
            "full": "img-20077202222.jpg"
        }
    }
```

I have a get function that can return multiple known properties:

```
switch ($numArgs) {
    case 1: return Merz::$db->{$args[0]}; break;
    case 2: return Merz::$db->{$args[0]}->{$args[1]}; break;
    case 3: return Merz::$db->{$args[0]}->{$args[1]}->{$args[2]}; break;
    default: return false; break;
}
```

The problem is that I can't assign `Merz::get('media')` to a variable:

```
$media = Merz::get('media');
foreach($media as $item) {
}
```

keep getting: "`Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`" - so I can't do a foreach, but I can `var_dump` it.

The var_dump is:

```
object(stdClass)[5]
    public '1' => 
       object(stdClass)[4]
         public 'title' => string 'Test Image' (length=10)
         public 'description' => string 'This is a test image' (length=20)
         public 'thumb' => string 'test.thumb.jpg' (length=14)
         public 'full' => string 'img-2007720.jpg' (length=15)
    public '2' => 
       object(stdClass)[2]
         public 'title' => string 'Test2 Image' (length=11)
         public 'description' => string 'This is a test image' (length=20)
         public 'thumb' => string 'test.thumb.jpg' (length=14)
         public 'full' => string 'img-20077202222.jpg' (length=19)
```

I'm trying to get the values 1 and 2 - which, needless to say, is dynamic.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated...

Comment: Why was this downvoted?
I am showing the problem clearly and have researched the issue.

Comment: What is that `Merz` thing?

Comment: Merz is the class that $db belongs to.